# Add cookies to a WMS request with OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, http-headers

I need to add a cookie in each `WMS` request.  I tried to do something like below, but I don't think this is the right way:

```
getURL : function(bounds) {
    var requestString = OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.prototype.getURL.apply(this, arguments);
    window.document.cookie="referrer="+window.location.origin;
    return this._encode(requestString) + "&KEY=" + this.navkey;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code to set the cookie is valid but the browser will only pass the cookie to sites in your own domain.

You may also want to set an expires date (otherwise gone when browser closes) and set the path to the root of your domain (otherwise only goes to your page).

```
document.cookie = "referrer=" 
    + window.location.origin 
    + '; expires=' + date.toUTCString() 
    + '; path=/';
```

Comment: Although your question really belongs on another forum, setting cookies is not GIS-specific.